# How to pass multiple functions/ objects to javascript classical constructor

Tags: javascript, constructor

I have the following code:

```
class simplePromise {

  constructor(resolveFn, rejectFn) {
    
    console.log(resolveFn, 'resolveFn') // (resolutionFunc, rejectionFunc) => {
    //   resolutionFunc(777);
    //   rejectionFunc();
    // }
    
    console.log(rejectFn, 'rejectFn') //undefined
  }

}

const promise1 = new simplePromise( (resolutionFunc, rejectionFunc) => {
  resolutionFunc(777);
  rejectionFunc();
});
```

As you can see, I'm trying to pass in 2 functions to the constructor. However, when I console.logged each of them out, I noticed that both functions are registered as 1 argument. In this case, how do I separate the 2 functions?

Comment: *"As you can see, I'm trying to pass in 2 functions to the constructor."* No, you are passing a single function, which in turn accepts two functions as arguments. You are confusing the constructor with the callback. If you want to replicate the built-in promise API then the constructor has to pass two functions to the callback function it receives.

Comment: @FelixKling is correct. You are just passing one function to your `new simplePromise` instance. That function you are passing to `new simplePromise` takes two arguments, which you would be passing to  `resolveFn`. You never even call `resolveFn(resolutionFuncPassedHere, rejectionFunctionPassedHere)`... I'm pretty sure you're still confused about the way it works, at this point. Practice, practice practice.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that you want to pass 2 functions to the `constructor`?

```
const promise1 = new simplePromise( (resolutionFunc, rejectionFunc) => {...}
```

this part of your code looks more like you want a single callback function that recieves 2 functions.

Like this:

```js
class SimplePromise {
  constructor(callback) {
    const resolveFn = (value) => {
      console.log("resolved with value", value);
    };

    const rejectFn = (error) => {
      console.log("rejected with error", error);
    }

    callback(resolveFn, rejectFn);
  }
}

const promise1 = new SimplePromise((resolutionFunc, rejectionFunc) => {
  console.log('resolutionFunc', resolutionFunc)
  console.log('rejectionFunc', rejectionFunc) //undefined

  resolutionFunc(777);
  rejectionFunc();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Not that this code has anything to do with a `Promise`, but you should study the following structure:

```js
class simplePromise{
  constructor(resolveFn, rejectFn){
    this.prop1 = 'prop1value'; this.prop2 = 'prop2value';
    resolveFn.call(this, 'Passing to first function argument'); // calling in simplePromise context
    rejectFn.call(this, 'Passing to second function argument');
  }
}

const promise1 = new simplePromise(function(funcOneArg){
  console.log(funcOneArg);;
  console.log("this.prop1 = '"+this.prop1+"';"); // see why `.call(this` is in `constructor`
  console.log("this.prop2 = '"+this.prop2+"';");
},
function(functionTwoArg){
  console.log('-'.repeat(45));
  console.log(functionTwoArg);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

So when you pass the arrow function to the `new simplePromise` constructor, that *entire function* is the first argument (resolveFn). In order to instantiate this the way you want, you need to define the resolutionFunc and rejectionFunc and then do it like so:

```js
const resolutionFunc = () => {do stuff}
const rejectionFunc = () => {do stuff}

const promise1 = new simplePromise(resolutionFunc, rejectionFunc)
```